# How to speed up the SELECT query of the following table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table whose create code is as follows :

```
         CREATE TABLE image_ref (
    region VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    district VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    district_name VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    lot_no VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    sp_no VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    form_no VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    imagename VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    updated_by VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    update_log DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ip VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    imgfetchstat VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (form_no)
        )
        COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
        ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

This table contains approximately 7,00,000 number of rows. I have an application developed using PHP. Somewhere I need to run the following query :

```
SELECT
    min(imagename) imagename
FROM
    image_ref 
WHERE
    district_name = '$sess_district' 
    AND 
        lot_no = '$sess_lotno' 
    AND 
        imgfetchstat = '0';
```

which is taking on average 1.560 sec. The form_no field only has unique values. After some job is done with the result set fetched, the imgfetchstat is required to be updated with a value 1. Now my requirement is that, whether I should use InnoDB or MyISAM? Also, the application is accessed by around 50 numbers of users in LAN. Is there any way out to run the above query little bit faster? because the imagename fetched is being used to load an image of resolution 500 x 498 into the browser and the it is taking enough time to load the image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `This table contains approximately 7 lakhs of rows.` What is a `lakhs` ?

Comment: you can use fulltext search for searching purpose

Comment: @ChristopheD A Lakh is 100,000

Comment: `A lakh or lac is a unit in the South Asian numbering system equal to one hundred thousand (100,000)`

Comment: Throw an index on the fields you have in your where clause: district_name, lot_no and imgfetchstat.

Comment: You have not spoken about indexes. Add some (tailored to your query) and you should be good to go.

Comment: You need to consider normalising the table and using foreign keys and indexes. For example the updated_by should be a index and a foreign key to another table with users. What happens if a user changes name or etc? The table is not set up in a suitable way

Comment: @user790454 None of his comparisons need fulltext searching.

Comment: @RonniSkansing That's a good general approach to database design, but it probably won't make much of a difference in query speed. He's not even using `updated_by` in this query.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the headsup, didnt even notice that.

Comment: Thanks to all. the updated_by field will be populated with the user_id which will not be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add indexes to your table (be aware that this will make the storage larger - but given your query, you should be able to use the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `product_id` (`product_id`)
```

For more information see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

You can add an index on a single column (which makes things nice for the DB, even it it uses a few of them on a query) but if you have a secific query that needs to REALLY run fast, you can add a multi-column index which is specific to your query:

```
ALTER TABLE image_ref ADD INDEX `someName` 
(`district_name`, `lot_no`, `imgfetchstat`)
```

Comment: @Samcoder I think you posted this comment in the wrong place :)

Comment: Thanks Fluffeh. I have adopted your last suggestion, but will it be OK to work with MyISAM for such dynamic application where transactions are carried out in seconds by around 50 concurrent users of the same table?

Comment: @Samcoder Yup, it certainly will. All an index does is to tell the database where records are physically stored - depending on the data in the row. If you have a date field for example (and index on it) the database will know not to search ALL the records when queried, but rather hone in directly on the right ones.